# Doesn't printf use __cdecl in VS2013

Tags: c, printf, calling-convention, cdecl

There is a such question in my interview ,today.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char *s="123456790";
    printf("%c,%c",*(char *)((int *)s+++1),*s);
    return 0;
}
```

my answer is 5,1, but the Interviewer said it's 5,2!
Of course, I knew the default calling convention in C is __cdecl,the argument-passing order is right to left, so I told to him about this. But he didn't believe it. Than we run it on VS2013.
IT SHOWED 5,2!!!!!

Now,I come back home and try it again on ideone.THE ANSWER IS 5,1!!!
http://ideone.com/sq6yRE
WHY?! I am so confused about it .Who can help me,please?

Comment: The calling convention doesn't imply anything about the order that the arguments are *evaluated*, just the order in which they are *passed*.

Comment: [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8785539/2065121) for a similar discussion.

Comment: Don't work for this company. Obviously they will give you unspecified tasks to work on...

Comment: +1 for fritzone's suggestion. Unspecified tasks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does incrementation takes place in printf statement in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13797279/how-does-incrementation-takes-place-in-printf-statement-in-c)

Comment: This is more than just unspecified - it's undefined behavior because having `s++` and `*s` in the same expression without an intervening sequence point is UB.

Comment: @MichaelBurr C99 6.5.2.2 Function calls 10. says _The order of evaluation of the function designator, the actual arguments, and subexpressions within the actual arguments is unspeciﬁed, but there is a sequence point before the actual call_.

Comment: @MohitJain: but there is no sequence point between the `s++` and the `*s` expressions.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Yes you are right. I misinterpreted. This line of code exhibits an undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C the order of evaluation of function argument is unspecified.

Code written below

```
int main()
{
  printf("%d %d\n", printf("Hi\n"), printf("Hello\n"));
  return 0;
}
```

May produce either

```
Hello
Hi
3 6
```

or

```
Hi
Hello
3 6
```

as output.

And neither you nor your interviewer should question why, how etc.

Comment: Thanks,I see it,now. C99 6.5.2.2 Function calls
10.The order of evaluation of the function designator, the actual arguments, and subexpressions within the actual arguments is unspeciﬁed, but there is a sequence point before the actual call.